# iOS RGB color is Incorrect?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, rgb, uicolor

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 8.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 135.0,213.0,0.0,1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I am draw a line use RGB(135,213,0),RGB(135,213,0) should be [green](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm). but iOS display yellow line!! why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to have the values in the range of [0,1]. Therefore you need to divide each value by 255.

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 135.0/255.0,213.0/255.0,0.0,1.0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Divide each value by 255 ie RGB(135/255,213/255,0)

Answer (score 3):

max value is 1.0, divide each argument by 255.0